# communicating swf files

Tags: file, flash

I have two swf files I would like communicate. I have a videoplaylist.swf and a player.swf. I would like to select a video from videoplaylist.swf and have it played in the player.swf. How do I do that? How am I going to dispatch the click event with the video url to the player.swf? from the videoplaylist.swf.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You've two choices. You can either use a small amount of Javascript glue code along with [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to call from Flash to Javascript and vice-versa, or to use [LocalConnection](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) for direct SWF to SWF communication.